# What are references for in Visual Studios?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I understand that this is bringing in an extra libraries that are pre-compiled by Microsoft but, for instance, is there a disadvantage of just adding every library under the sun? I can also see that is, by default, adds the most used libraries to any project.

Does it actually do anything to the output binary when my application is compiled, because I was under the impression that most of these libraries are part of the .NET framework anyways?

So other than custom libraries, what is the point?

Comment: Wouldn't your app become rather large with ever library under the sun?

Comment: Well my thinking was, if the libraries are all included in the runtime, why would they be included in the output binary?

Comment: your right that your output binary wouldn't be large. Your project that would become very large, maybe even take a long time to compile with so many references to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing that stops you from doing this.  The compiler is going to be bogged down by having to load all the declarations from the metadata of all of these assemblies but that shouldn't take more than a handful of seconds on a slow disk.  Pretty sure identifier lookup is amortized O(1) so it should not noticeably slow down the actual compilation.  Namespace names in the .NET framework were carefully picked to never cause a collision.  The output assembly will only have a list of the references that actually get used in the code.

The only objection against it is, well, it is not **elegant**. Your team mates will whisper behind your back.  Whomever is picked to maintain your project some day will start looking for another job the instant he sees your project.  Being considered *sloppy* is the worst kind of label for a programmer, a reputation that's very hard to live down.

Comment: See up till now I have been removing every reference I can, simply because I thought it looked neater in the menu, but it got me thinking...Am I actually hindering myself, does it remove certain things from Intellisense or something like that? I can seem to get away with just having the System reference for most projects...

Comment: Well, don't knock yourself out either by micro-managing it.  A project template pre-selects the common references, nobody is going to hold it against you if you don't trim those.  You will not "hinder" yourself by removing an unused reference, other than maybe having to add it back later when you make changes.